# Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, timeout

```
it 'computes correctly when on & off have a list at cronRange[4]', ->
    @component.set('cronRanges', [Ember.Object.create({
      on: "* * * 3 3,1,5"
      off: "* * * 3 3,1,5"
    })])
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 2)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.false
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 5)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.true
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 1)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.true
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 3)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.true
```

this is an ember unit test that fails with the error that is the is the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ember, try wrapping async calls in Ember.run => [read this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html)

What I understood is, if you're setting something `@set(..,..)` to the `@store()`, in the unit tests, and get this error, then you should use `Ember.run =>`

Also, remember the arrow has to be a fat arrow, (i made that mistake once of using `->` instead of `=>`)it's because of javascript scope, read up on it if you are interested.

Solution: observe that I just added line # 2

```
 it 'computes correctly when on & off have a list at cronRange[4]', ->
  Ember.run =>
    @component.set('cronRanges', [Ember.Object.create({
      on: "* * * 3 3,1,5"
      off: "* * * 3 3,1,5"
    })])
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 2)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.false
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 5)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.true
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 1)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.true
    @component.set('dayOfWeek', 3)
    expect(@component.get('inRange')).to.be.true
```